# Breeze doesn't post navigation properties

Tags: breeze

I inherited an OData service that exposes - among other things - a type called Evaluation. This type contains a lot of primitive type properties (int, bool mostly) and two navigation properties/links to other entities.

Breeze is configured to use the v3/'original' odata adapter:
`breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'odata', true);`

If I create a new entity

`var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('odataEndPointHere');

manager.fetchMetadata().then(() => {
    var newEvaluation = manager.createEntity('Evaluation', {Name:'Foo'});
});`

then this newEvaluation will reference all primitive fields and the navigation properties (called Validation - a TPH type - and Replacements - a ~normal~ 1:1 entity relation). If I `expand()` that relation, I can query for existing Evaluations and will see the expected Validation value.

Grabbing an existing Validation instance and assigning it seems to work as well:
`manager.fetchEntityByKey('Validation', existingIdHere).then(validation => {
    newEvaluation.Validation = validation; // works, while assigning a non-entity throws
});`

But if I call `manager.saveChanges();` the server reports that there's no (mandatory) Validation link. Looking at the POST to the $batch endpoint I see that breeze really only posts a subset of the Evaluation type, only posts the primitive fields and none of the navigation properties. This happens for both existing (fetched and updated) and new (createEntity) objects.

Now, I understand that I've yet to create a small test case - given that this is a service that I cannot directly control I'm still trying to figure out how I'm going to provide a reduced recipe for reproduction.

That said:

- breeze can query all my entities, just fine. Expanding the navigation properties works flawlessly
- breeze completely ignores the very same properties during `saveChanges()` for me
- (unrelated?) breeze offers no way for me to set the FK ID only (http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/navigation-properties.html, "Setting the Foreign Key directly") although it does list the navigation properties in `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Evaluation").navigationProperties`

Edit:

The $metadata result contain this for the entities in question:

`<EntityType>
    <!-- snip the rest --->
    <NavigationProperty Name="Evaluations" Relationship="MyNamespace.Entities.FK_Evaluation_Validation" ToRole="Evaluation" FromRole="Validation" />
</EntityType>`

and later:

`<AssociationSet Name="FK_Evaluation_Validation" Association="MyNamespace.Entities.FK_Evaluation_Validation">
    <End Role="Validation" EntitySet="Validations" />
    <End Role="Evaluation" EntitySet="Evaluations" />
</AssociationSet>`

Comment: In the metadata, is the FK defined for the navigation property?

Comment: I'd go with 'no'. The associationName is correct (the FK, the name in the DB), the types seem correct, but all the *foreignKeyNames* (inv-, -OnServer) arrays are empty

Comment: Looking at the result of the $metadata endpoint the ```Entity``` contains a ```NavigationProperty``` with Name, RelationShip, ToRole, FromRole and there's a ```AssociationSet```, Name being the FK association in the DB, Association being a link to the RelationShip from above. Two lines, ```End``` with Role/EntitySet attributes. Role being the link to ToRole/FromRole from above, EntitySet the .. EntitySet name.

Comment: Seems like you may have the problem described [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/odata.html#metadata-fail)

Comment: Hmm.. While the problem seems to match my issue exactly I do have two issues with that. 1) I'm not sure if I can change the service, so that might be a the end of the experiment already and 2) I thought that this is WebAPI specific. My service is - afaik, based on the limited source I've seen - WCF based, using System.Data.Services.DataService<T> and the only configuration there uses DataServiceConfiguration (based on IEdmModel etc.). Will look into that though - I understand that you're saying that these arrays cannot be empty (although queries work, .expand() works). Correct?

Comment: Right, Breeze needs to know the foreign key for a navigation property.